# Decreasing the value of a number in an array if next to a certain value in the array

Tags: java, arrays

My code is suppose to take an array and decrease a number's value by half if it is next to a zero in the array. I’m trying to fix an error in my code where it won’t properly decrease numbers in my array if they are next to the number zero and zero is in the first or last position in the array. I want my code to output this:

```
Day 0: {0,6,7,9,3,5,6,1}
Day 1: {0,3,7,9,3,5,6,1}
Day 2: {0,1,7,9,3,5,6,1}
Day 3: {0,0,7,9,3,5,6,1}
Day 4: {0,0,3,9,3,5,6,1}
Day 5: {0,0,1,9,3,5,6,1}
Day 6: {0,0,0,4,3,5,6,1}
Day 7: {0,0,0,2,3,5,6,1}
Day 8: {0,0,0,1,3,5,6,1}
Day 8: {0,0,0,0,1,5,6,1}
Day 9: {0,0,0,0,0,5,6,1}
Day 10: {0,0,0,0,0,2,6,1}
Day 11: {0,0,0,0,0,1,6,1}
Day 12: {0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1}
Day 13: {0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1}
Day 14: {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1}
Day 15: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
Day 16: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
Day 17: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
---extinct---
```

However it outputs this instead:

```
Day 295279: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295280: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295281: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295282: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295283: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295284: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
Day 295285: 0, 0, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6, 1.
```

It keeps on repeating to infinity and I’m not sure why it’s happening. Here's my code:

```
public class Final {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] settlement = {0,6,7,9,3,5,6,1};

 int daycont=0;
 System.out.println("Day 0: "+settlement[0]+", "+settlement[1]+", "+settlement[2]+", "+settlement[3]+", "+settlement[4]+", "+settlement[5]+", "+settlement[6]+", "+settlement[7]+".");
 while(settlement[0]!=0 || settlement[1]!=0 ||settlement[2]!=0 || settlement[3]!=0 || settlement[4]!=0 || settlement[5]!=0 || settlement[6]!=0 || settlement[7]!=0) { 
  daycont++;
 for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
  if (settlement[i]==0) {
   if(i!=7){
   i++;
   settlement[i]= settlement[i]/2;}
   if(i!=1 && i!=0)
   i=i-2;
   settlement[i]= settlement[i]/2;
   i++;
  }
 }

 System.out.println("Day "+daycont+": "+settlement[0]+", "+settlement[1]+", "+settlement[2]+", "+settlement[3]+", "+settlement[4]+", "+settlement[5]+", "+settlement[6]+", "+settlement[7]+".");
 }

for (int extcounter=0; extcounter<8; extcounter++) {
 if (settlement[extcounter]==0) {
  extcounter++;
  if (extcounter==8)
   System.out.println("----EXTINCT----");

 }

}}
}
```

Can someone explain why it’s not working properly? I’m stumped I tried googling and browsing stack overflow but, I couldn’t find anything. (Note I’m using a one dimensional array and I’ve only recently started Java so I have a very basic understanding and some of the code I’ve seen on Stack Overflow I don’t really understand) Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and compare actual values with your expectations along the way.

Comment: Never mind I just ran your original code with this array: {3,6,7,0,3,5,6,1}; not with {0,6,7,9,3,5,6,1}, sorry

Comment: Okay, yeah the code works whenever the 0 is not in the first or last position in the array.If you figure out how to get it working when 0 is in the first or last position in the array please tell me. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < settlement.length; i++) {

            if (settlement[i] == 0) {
                if (i != settlement.length - 1) {
                    settlement[i + 1] = settlement[i + 1] / 2;
                }
                if (i != 0) {
                    settlement[i - 1] = settlement[i - 1] / 2;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This ones works! Thank you so much I've been stumped on this for days now! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be able to do the task.

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
 {
      if(i<6&& settlement[i]==0 && settlement[i+1]>0)
      {
            settlement[i+1]=settlement[i+1]/2;
      }
}
```

Comment: It works if 0 is in the first place, however if zero is placed in the last place in the array I get this: Day : 10, 3, 1, 10, 3, 2, 4, 0. on repeat for infinity. I think I can work with the code you made though and make it work for the last number as well. If you figure out code for getting the code to work  if 0 is the last number in the array please post it. Thank you :D